# Using VB.NET to format a date

Tags: .net, vb.net, date

Just started upgrading to VB.Net from VB6.

```
txtFrom.Text = "1/8"
txtFrom.Text = Format(txtFrom.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

This code produces `DD/MM/YYYY` in the text box.

What should I do to produce `01/08/13`?

Comment: Without year in input which year you expect in output?

Answer (score 5):

Parse the date. Reformat the date.

```
Dim d As Date = Date.ParseExact(txtFrom.Text, "d/M", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
txtFrom.Text = d.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
```

[Custom date format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Won't this create a date with a 0 (epoch-based) for the year value? So, January 8, 0001 A.D.? I expect he'll need another piece to put the current or prior year in there.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: I tested it a little while afterwards, and [apparently not](http://ideone.com/qe4QAR).

Answer (score 1):

The format function with `"dd/MM/yyyy"` will format a date object, not a string. You can convert the string from the textbox to a date using CDate:

```
txtFrom.Text = Format(CDate(txtFrom.Text), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

You might want to use `IsDate` or a Try-Catch block in case `txtFrom.Text` is an invalid date.

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do to produce 01/08/13?

```
dd/MM/yy
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim sFormat As System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo = New System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo()
sFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"
txtFrom.Text = Format(Convert.ToDateTime(txtFrom.Text+Now.Year.ToString(), sFormat), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```