# VB.Net: Writing To Excel Workbook as Text

Tags: excel, vb.net, text, worksheet

I have written the following function...

```
Public Function writeAUTLSheet(doc As XDocument, myNameSpaces As Dictionary(Of String, XNamespace), theSheet As Excel.Worksheet)
    'Grab the number of the last row to not overwrite 
    Dim rowNumber As Integer = getLastRow(theSheet)

    For Each myName As XElement In doc.Descendants.Elements(myNameSpaces("ns4") + "autl")
        theSheet.Cells(rowNumber, 1) = doc.Descendants.Elements(myNameSpaces("ns") + "number").Value
        theSheet.Cells(rowNumber, 2) = myName.Descendants(myNameSpaces("ns") + "id").Value
        theSheet.Cells(rowNumber, 3) = myName.Descendants(myNameSpaces("ns") + "name").Value
        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
    Next

End Function
```

It runs as expected, but some values are written as "General" and others are written as "Date". This leads to values such as 07-2-3018 being turned into 7/2/3018. Then if I change that cell to "Text" or "General"(manually) it turns into "408525".

Is there a way to specify that I want it to be written as text to achieve 07-2-3-18 being written?

Comment: You want it to show "408525"?  Try `theSheet.Cells(rowNumber,3).NumberFormat = "General"` (if `3` is the column you need it for).

Comment: @BruceWayne Dang it, I didn't specify the end goal. The end goal is for it to be written as 07-2-3018. Will edit.

Comment: @BruceWayne there doesn't seem to be the option to use `NumberFormat`

Comment: (Ah, my mistake, I didn't notice the VB.Net tag)

Comment: @BruceWayne all good man! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with VB.Net, but does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19082048/4650297) help?  Also, just to be sure, you want `07-2-3-18`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put data that might be a string, or might be a date, Excel does wacky things with it, as you've observed, because it has no way of knowing whether the data you've provided should be one type or another.

Usually, anything that *can* be interpreted as a `Date` type, is interpreted as such. So, `1/1/2017` would be a valid date but `13/47/5047` cannot be, so Excel will treat the latter as a string literal, the former as a `Date` type. If a value is considered a `Date`, then it is also a `Long` numeric. The `408525` value is the long numeric representation of the `Date` value `7/2/3018`.

There should be a `NumberFormat` property of your `Cells` object (which is an `Excel.Range` type), but the `NumberFormat` doesn't change the underlying *value*, and it's the interpretation of the *value* which is confusing Excel and causing it to represent date-like values as Dates.

You can always prepend the cell value with an apostrophe, which will force Excel to interpret as string, e.g.:

```
theSheet.Cells(rowNumber, 2) = "'" + myName.Descendants(myNameSpaces("ns") + "id").Value
```