# Column type for excel when extracting file to Browser

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have a method which is use to extract excel by copying it to a response and downloading it to the browser. Everything checks out fine apart from the two formatting issues which are encountered.

1 . You see i have some values which are defined like '10-2', the problem is that excel is treating it like a date(which should not happen).

2 . All the Zeroes in the column are disappearing.

I presume changing the column to a text type might resolve the issue but i cant seem to figure out how to do it.

Would be a great help if someone can help me with this.

The code i am using is below:

```
 Dim name As String = "SweepstakesReport_" & RewardCodeForName & "_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    Dim tmp As String = ""
    Dim tmptime As String = ""
    Dim ExcelFile As String = ""
    Dim stwWriter As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter
    Dim htwWriter As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stwWriter)

    Dim dgGrid As DataGrid = New DataGrid
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds = Session("dsRedeemed")

    dgGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
    dgGrid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = True
    dgGrid.DataBind()
    dgGrid.RenderControl(htwWriter)

    ExcelFile = name & ".xls"

    Response.Clear()
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", ExcelFile))
    'Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    'Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
    'Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble())

    'Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"

    Response.Write(stwWriter.ToString)
    Response.End()
```

Thanks,
Haris.

Comment: The presumption that this "should not happen" is wrong :) [Excel treats any date-like string as a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720499/vb-net-writing-to-excel-workbook-as-text/), unless its explicitly told not to. While this yields undesired results in cases like yours, this is very much the normal, expected behavior. To avoid this, you will need to ensure that these cell values are explicitly string literals, and this can be achieved by prepending a single-quote (`'`) to their values, or by writing the file as .txt and then using the import wizard to specify column type.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the quick reply, I tried doing that but i cant seem to concatenate the single quote anywhere. Also i cant seem to get the cell values in the code. Sorry to ask but is there a way that you can tell me how to get the cell values from the HTML? sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Can you update your code to show how you attempt to do this?

Comment: Sorry David, but that is where i am having trouble. On how exactly should i get the columns so i can format them :(

Comment: You said "I tried doing that but I can't seem to concatenate the single quote". Please *show me what you tried*.

Comment: well, i just did this (i know its not correct but still) ,

`htwWriter+= "<td>" & htwWriter &  "&nbsp;</td>" `

Comment: well I am not familiar with this `System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter` but you will need the &nbsp; or the single-quote *BEFORE* the individual values, not *after*.